# Linq, OData and WCF : “the method join is not supported”

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, linq, odata

I'm trying to recover and display data from multiple table. o i've done a mutliple join like that :

```
var prod = from product in context.PRODUCT
    join islocated in context.ISAUDITEDIN on product.PRODUCT_ID equals islocated.PRODUCT_ID
    join location in context.LOCATION on islocated.LOCATION_ID equals location.LOCATION_ID
    orderby location.LOCATION_ID
    group new
    {
       Location_ID = location.LOCATION_ID,
       Product_ID = product.PRODUCT_ID
    } by location.LOCATION_ID into locat
    select new {
       Location_ID = locat.Key,
       Product = locat
    };
```

where context is the OData that result to a call from a web service. That link is working : when I do a simple select, I'm able to recover the data.
Then, I want to display the data that are in the result. So i've created a Dictionnary :

```
Dictionary<string,List<ProductModel>> dict = new Dictionary<string,List<ProductModel>>();
foreach (var locat in prod) {
    List<ProdctModel> products = new List<ProductModel>();
    foreach (var p in locat.Product)
    {
        products.Add(new ProductModel(p.Location_ID, p.Product_ID));
    }
    dict.Add(locat.Location_ID.ToString(), products);
}
```

Where ProductModel is a simple class like that:

```
public class ProdctModel
{
    public int locationID{get; set;}
    public int productID{get; set;}
    public ProdctModel(int location_ID, int product_ID)
    {
        this.locationID = location_ID;
        this.productID = product_ID;
    }
}
```

But when i'm running that, i've got the following :

```
“the method join is not supported”
Ligne 131 :            Dictionary<string,List<ProdctModel>> dict = new Dictionary<string,List<ProdctModel>>();
Ligne 132 :            foreach (var locat in prod) {
```

How to solve that ? I've seen a couple of things by using method .Expand() instead of join but I dunno how to use it : could you help me ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I never used the odata with linq, but im assuming you can't join different remote resources. Try to get the objects to memory first, and then do the join:

```
var products = context.PRODUCT.ToList();
var islocateds = context.ISAUDITEDIN.ToList();
var locations = context.LOCATION.ToList();


var prod = from product in products
                       join islocated in islocateds on product.PRODUCT_ID equals islocated.PRODUCT_ID
                       join location in locations on islocated.LOCATION_ID equals location.LOCATION_ID
                       orderby location.LOCATION_ID
                       group new
                       {
                           Location_ID = location.LOCATION_ID,
                           Product_ID = product.PRODUCT_ID
                       } by location.LOCATION_ID into locat
                       select new {
                           Location_ID = locat.Key,
                           Product = locat
                       };
```

Remember that this will download all 3 tables.

EDIT
Also, the reason you are getting the exception when creating dictionary, is that the "prod" varialble is an IEnumerable- it executes the request only when you do "foreach" or something similiar.

Comment: I think the same @DawoodAbbasi but what's is the good answer for this?

Comment: @Leandro According to [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee622463(v=vs.110).aspx) join method is still not supported. Derbie, as a consumer of the web service can't do anything about this. To make it work, one would have to use different framework for the service. Assuming such framework exist.